# How to display blank item in the combobox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

For a `Combobox`, I am getting a list of values from the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`.

I am assigning the values like this:

```
this.cmbSqlServer.DataSource = this.SqlInstancesCollection;
```

I don't want to see the first item in the list in the `Combobox`, unless I selected it.

How do I display a blank field in the `Combobox` when nothing is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to reset the `SelectedItem`. Just set `SelectedIndex` to -1.

```
this.cmbSqlServer.DataSource = this.SqlInstancesCollection;
this.cmbSqlServer.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Working fine as expected.